# How to change toolbar and navigation bar color.

Tags: java, android

How can i change the color of toolbar and navigation bar in android 4.0 + like this image

https://s9.postimg.org/e6gxw7c2n/20170503_081922.jpg

I am using appcompat-v7:22.2.1 and support:design:22.2.1

Thankx.

Answer (score 1):

You can set naviagtion bar color
in style.xml

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

and you can set toolbar color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>


</style>
```

[image: Check this image]

Comment: I already try this method but both statusbar and navigation bar are black

Comment: Hi, create style.xml(v21) and add this code, and check

Answer (score 0):

Use Theme Editor in studio to personalise your app (Double-shift) and type theme editor

adjust color primary for toolbar
adjust color primary dark for system bar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUxCf.png)